# How can I solve $\tiny\begin{cases} \dfrac{dx}{dt} = t^2 x^2 y\\ \dfrac{dy}{dt} = -t^2 y^2 x \end{cases}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have:

$$\begin{cases}
\dfrac{dx}{dt} = t^2 x^2 y\\
 \dfrac{dy}{dt} = -t^2 y^2 x
\end{cases}$$

How do I go about solving this system of equations?

---

I tried separation of variables however because of the extra $y$ term in the $\frac{dx}{dt}$ and $x$ term in $\frac{dy}{dt}$ I am unsure how to start.

Comment: Have  you tried cancelling out variable $t$?

Comment: @Jack how can i justify that? and how would i go about doing it

Comment: @RobertThompson The chain rule, perhaps? $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)}{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)}$.

Comment: @arthur good idea, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the two equations,

$$\frac{dx}x+\frac{dy}y=0,$$ so that $xy=3C$.

Then

$$\frac{dx}x=3Ct^2$$ and $$x=C'e^{Ct^3},y=C''e^{-Ct^3}$$ with $C'C''=3C$.

Comment: Why $\frac{dx}{x}=-\frac{dy}{y}$?

Comment: @Ramanujan: because $t^2xy\,dt=t^2xy\,dt$, maybe.

Comment: Are you sure you are allowed to divide by $x$ and by $y$?

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis: I am sure I am not when $x=0$ or $y=0$.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Jack, you could consider eliminating $t$ from both equations leaving you with the following:

$$ t^2 = \frac{1}{x^2y}\frac{dx}{dt} = -\frac{1}{y^2x}\frac{dy}{dt}$$

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{y}{x}$$ which is now variable separable.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{dy}{dt} \frac{dt}{dx} = \frac{-t^2y^2x}{t^2x^2y}$$

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{y}{x}$$

Comment: Don't forget the minus sign.

Comment: @Rumplestillskin thanks :D

Comment: @ramanujan thank you, i can't believe i didn't think of this

Answer (score 0):

Note that:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}$$

Hence, you obtain the following differential equation:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{y}{x}$$

Now, separate the variables:

$$\int \frac{1}{y}~dy=-\int \frac{1}{x}~dx$$

From here on, it should be relatively straightforward.

Comment: thank you, i realise i was being silly in not noticing this

Answer (score -1):

First observe that
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(xy)=x\frac{dy}{dt}+y\frac{dx}{dt}=0. 
$$
Thus $x(t)y(t)=c_1$, for some constant $c_1\in\mathbb R$. The system now becomes
$$\begin{cases}
\dfrac{dx}{dt} =  c_1t^2x\\
 \dfrac{dy}{dt} = -c_1t^2y.
\end{cases}$$
General solution of the system is hence
$$
x(t)=c_2\mathrm{e}^{c_1t^3/3},\quad y(t)=c_3\mathrm{e}^{-c_1t^3/3},
$$
where $c_2c_3=c_1$.

Comment: $x=e^{t^3}, y=2e^{-t^3}$ is allowed by your general solution, though it is not a solution of the original ODE.

Comment: I added a sentence: *where $c_2c_3=c_1$*

Comment: Great, you are coming closer to a clone of my answer.

Comment: Not really. In my answer I DO NOT divide by quantities which may vanish.

Comment: Instead, you multiply by quantities which may vanish. Not more rigorous.

Comment: Which quantity may vanish?

Comment: The same as mine.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with multiplication by zero. Division by zero is the problem

Comment: Stupid me, your are right. I forgot that $1=2\iff0\cdot1=0\cdot2$.